# AMFPHP Serializer/DeSerializer issue

Tags: apache-flex, amfphp

i'm new to using amfphp 1.9, i managed to get it working and able to retrieve data from database, but unable to write to the database. i;m using IExternalizable code like this :

```
public function writeExternal(output:IDataOutput):void {
    output.writeObject(id);
}

public function readExternal(input:IDataInput):void {
    id=input.readObject();
    name=input.readObject();
    _url=input.readObject();
}
```

what could be the function mapping for the above flex code in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have to I would stay clear of IExternalizable and just send your data in arrays and the like. Now, if you must, externalizable data is available as _externalizedData for AmfPHP 2.0 and later as described here in the Array Collection
http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/documentation/data-types/

I don't know about 1.9 though.